# Finding information about 1920s adoption in New York State?

Tags: new-york-state, adoption, 1920s

I am trying to find out information on my great great uncle. I need some advice on how to go about finding the information. All I know about him other than his name at birth which I am unable to post (because he was born less than 100 years ago) is:

- He was born in the 1920s in New York State.
- He had a brother, whose name I am unable to post, because he too may have been born less than 100 years ago.
- His parents were John A. Caulfield and Charlotte Lane.
- He was adopted when he was very young, therefore I am having trouble finding any info on him.

Any ideas? I would really like to be able to find out where he ended up living and if he had any kids.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Due to our privacy policy on anybody born less than 100 years ago, who may potentially still be living, I have had to remove the names of your great grand uncle and his brother.  Please read that policy carefully in our [help/on-topic] because it sounds like you may well be able to demonstrate that the brother is now deceased, and thus can be discussed.

Comment: If this is the brother, https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVV7-PJ9V (deceased in 1986), then we will be able to reinstate his name to the question.  Please confirm.